# How to make a file_exist from a server to the local machine?

Tags: php

how to test if a file exist on the current computer using the application ?

I try to put the full url at my file like this, but it doesn't work :

```
if(file_exists("C:/wamp/www/project/photo/".$nom_photo))
        {
            echo "file exist";
            $extension=pathinfo("C:/wamp/www/project/photo/".$nom_photo,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            echo "<br>";
            $nom=md5($nom_photo.time().rand(0, 99999)).".".$extension;
            echo $nom;
            rename("C:/wamp/www/project/photo/".$nom_photo,"C:/wamp/www/project/photo/".$nom);
            echo "<br>";


        }
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Just to mention - basing your paths on the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (the root www / public_html folder) or `__FILE__` (the current file) is a much better practice than using absolute paths like `"C:/wamp/www/project/photo"`

Answer (score 3):

PHP operates server side and has **NO ACCESS** to the files on the machine running the web browser, unless they are indeed the same machine.

If you are meaning to find a way to test if a file exists on the web server, the [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) function you mentioned should find it.  There are many reasons this might fail, including [safe_mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php), [file permissions](http://www.google.com/search?q=file+permissions+windows+wamp), and using the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

The server doesn't have any access to the clients filesystem, this would be a major security flaw.

Also javascript is sandboxed so you couldn't do it on the client side either.

The only way I can think of doing this is to get the user to download a separate application that looks for the file and reports back to the server.